# Subscribing to the odometry topic

Tags: ros, topic, stageros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am very new to ROS and I'm using stageros as a simulator for my robot. I'm trying to write a c++ application that subscribes to the odometry topic (of type nav_msgs) and just write the contents to terminal.  I have tried everything but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9834/subscribing-to-the-odometry-topic/) by [Nico](https://answers.ros.org/users/476/nico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-28

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend reading the [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial. If that still doesn't help, asking more specific questions about the problems you're having will make it easier for people to offer advice.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1